# SL4A Qpython error

Tags: android, sl4a, qpython

I've tried to use Qpython and everything seemed to be fine. But later, when I started script with lines

```
import androidhelper
droid = androidhelper.Android()
```

It gave me error

> socket.gaierror: [Errno 4] non-recoverable failure in name resolution.

After some minutes of searching I've found that the problem might be with sl4a server. But Qpython says that it's running. So what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The SL4A service has to be running:

- For 3L version: main menu -> 3 dots (top right corner) -> SL4A
  Service manage -> (tap) Start SL4A Service.
- For OL version: main menu -> More -> (tap) SL4A Server. It should show "SL4A Server is running" right below the option.

Close (restart) your console if it has been running already - internal address of SL4A service is fetched on module import, so if you restart the service after importing `androidhelper`, it won't work for that interpreter - you'll have to open a new one.

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting(disable/enable) S4LA in QPython settings I did this before changing name.
*Change name of that variable, droid gave me same error. "Droidr" works for me just fine. 
Actually I don't know where is problem, probably this variable is already used somewhere in SL4A.*

Answer (score -1):

This is a problem with resolving a ip:namespace pair on your socket layer.
It most likely should be a problem with your DNS somewhere.

Comment: So, am I able to fix it somehow?

Comment: i believe this is non-specific to sl4a. this error can be prompted for all types of network operations. you might be using a bad hostname in your code and it can't be resolved, you may have incorrect dns server ips on your device (or your router), and i have even seen this problem when logging into public networks that expect you to agree to their terms before surfing the net as it blocks dns queries before acceptance. Not sure if thats it but those are some reasons for a socket error like that.

Comment: If you are not doing any networking in your python script it is probably corruption in qpython as your script needs to connect to the sl4a rpc server to access the java api code. its probably looking for the localhost address and failing for some reason. try re-installing and see if you get the same problem. qpython stores the python standard library on external storage, wipe that too for a clean wipe and reload.

Comment: I've already tried reinstalling and checked both qpython and qpython3 versions. Both giving me same error with sl4a

Comment: No, this is not a problem with "network operations". SL4A uses RPC socket there. It tries to connect to `(os.environ['AP_HOST'], os.environ['AP_PORT'])` (`("127.0.0.1", 37235)` in my case). Saying that it's "a problem with resolving a ip:namespace pair on your socket layer" probably steers the reader in the wrong direction. It's like saying that a crashing plane is "a problem with lift - gravity - thrust - drag force system".

Comment: This is an old thread and I haven't used sl4a in a bit but I still think it's a DNS issue for desu. In the RPC case, python socket package wouldn't need to use DNS on a loop back ip. It has nothing to look up in regards to DNS.